# Debugging using the PO command

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

Why does this debugger command works:

```
(lldb) **po indexPath**
<NSIndexPath: 0x1c0711b0> {length = 2, path = 3 - 0}
```

but this does not:

```
(lldb) **po [indexPath section]**
[no Objective-C description available]
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for primitive types you have to use 'p' , 'po' is for objects

p = print

po = print object

so for example

```
(lldb) p [indexPath section]
```

Comment: When using this, I get the error message: `error: no known method '-section'; cast the message send to the method's return type`. Any ideas?

Comment: when the debugger can't recognize the input type just cast it like this 'p [(NSIndexPath*)indexPath section]'

Comment: weird... than try casting the return value as well 'p (NSInteger)[(NSIndexPath*)indexPath section]

Comment: This works now. It would be great if there would be a more user-friendly way to debug this :-)

Comment: with lldb you can actually call methods ot funcions and print the return values, not only print variables, for example 'po NSHomeDirectory()', but you have to pay attention to nested breakpoints and recoursive funcions, in this case the debugger will print an error

Answer (score 1):

Because the section is not an object, [it is an integer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSIndexPath/section).

Comment: Great! I did not thing about this. Is there an equivalent command of `PO` for integers?

Comment: Just "p" which is short for "print". [Good tutorial on LLVM debugging](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html)